# Interpreting group-theoretic sentences as statements about algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, model-theory

Suppose we are given a sentence in the language of groups, e.g. $\phi=\forall x\forall y(x\cdot y=y\cdot x)$, and suppose that we are also given the data defining an algebraic group $G/k$. One can interpret $\phi$ in such a way that it makes sense as applied to $G$: if $m:G\times G\rightarrow G$ is the multiplication map, then $\phi$ can be interpretted as $$\forall x,y:\operatorname{Spec}(k)\rightarrow G, m\circ (x\times y)=m\circ (y\times x),$$ where $x\times y$ and $y\times x$ are the morphisms $\operatorname{Spec}(k)\rightarrow G\times G$ induced by $x$ and $y$. We could also interpret $x$ and $y$ as morphisms from *any* scheme $S\rightarrow G$, but at the end of the day I'll only be interested in the $k$-points. If we make a further assumption that $G=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ and that $R$ is finite type over $k$, then we can further "decompose" the sentence $\phi$ into a sentence in the language of rings. Indeed, if $R = k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/(f_1,\dotsc, f_m)$, then the morphisms $x$ and $y$ can be interpreted as solutions (in $k$) to the system of polynomial equations $\{f_i=0\}_{i=1}^m$ and the multiplication of the group scheme can be expressed by the co-multiplication on $R$.

Let's work out a specific example. Say $R$ is the group algebra $kG$ where $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $R\cong k[x]/(x^2-1)$ with co-multiplication given by $\Delta(z)=z\otimes z$. Then $G=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is an affine group scheme over $k$. Let $\phi$ be the sentence from above: $\phi=\forall x\forall y(x\cdot y=y\cdot x)$. Then the group $G(k)$ satisfies the sentence $\phi$ if and only if the field $k$ satisfies the sentence $$\forall x\forall y (x^2=1 \wedge y^2=1\implies\forall a\forall b[(a+bx)\cdot(a+by)=(a+by)\cdot(a+bx)]).$$

So here's the "theorem": given a sentence $\phi$ in the language of groups and the data defining an *affine* algebraic group $G/k$, there is an "equivalent" sentence $\psi$ in the language of rings so that $G(k)\models \phi$ if and only if $k\models \psi$.

I have a few questions about this procedure:

1. Is there a name for this type of "unpacking" procedure?
2. Can this procedure be extended to algebraic groups which are not affine? In particular, I would like to apply this procedure to *projective* algebraic groups, i.e. to elliptic curves and abelian varieties. This should be possible, but some extra care ought to be taken as morphisms of projective varieties are not as simple as morphisms of affine varieties. At worst, I would expect there to be some collection of sentences $\{\psi_i\}_{i\in I}$ so that $G(k)\models \phi$ if and only if $k\models \psi_i$ for each $i\in I$.

The impetus for this question came from attempting to better understand the Lefschetz principle as it is usually applied in arithmetic geometry. For instance, one might prove that if $E/k$ is an elliptic curve and $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic zero, then $E[n](k)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ by appealing to the Lefschetz principle: all of the data defining $E$ (the variety itself, the multiplication map, etc.) can be defined over a finitely generated extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, which can then be embedded into $\mathbb{C}$; the structure of the $n$-torsion points over $\mathbb{C}$ is known; some easy Galois theory will tell us that this is sufficient to know the structure $E[n](k)$.

Provided we can extend the translation-scheme above to work for projective algebraic groups, we can provide another proof of this fact that's more in line with the spirit of this question: consider the abelian scheme $\mathcal{E}\rightarrow S$ where $S=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[a,b][1/(4a^3+27b^2)])$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is the closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^2\times S$ cut out by $Y^2Z=X^3+aXZ^2+bZ^3$. This family has a special property: if $k$ is characteristic zero and $E/k$ is an elliptic curve, then there is a morphism $s:\operatorname{Spec}(k)\rightarrow S$ so that the fiber $E_s/k$ is isomorphic to $E$ (as an elliptic curve) over $k$. Here's the punchline: consider the sentence $\phi =\text{"there are exactly } n^2 \text{ elements which are killed by } n\text"$, i.e. $$\phi =  \exists x_1,\dots, x_{n^2}(\bigwedge\limits_{i\neq j} (x_i\neq x_j)\wedge\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^{n^2} (n\cdot x_i = 0))\forall y (n\cdot y =0 \implies \bigvee\limits_{i=1}^{n^2} (y=x_i)).$$
Assuming we can extend our translation-scheme above to projective algebraic groups, there will be a sentence $\psi$ in the language of rings so that $E_s(k)\models \phi$ if and only if $k\models \psi$. As the sentence $\psi$ depends not only on $\phi$, but also on the data defining $E_s/k$, i.e. $\psi$ depends on $a$ and $b$ as well, I'll write $\psi=\psi(\phi,a,b)$. Putting it all together, we discover the following first-order sentence in the language of rings: $$\chi = \forall a\forall b (4a^3+27b^2\neq 0\implies \psi(\phi,a,b)).$$
When we allow values from a field $k$ of characteristic zero, the sentence $\chi$ is equivalent to the statement that all elliptic curves $E/k$ satisfy $\lvert E[n](k)\rvert=n^2$. We finally come to the point of all this — we can use the Lefschetz principle as it is known in model theory: if $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and $\chi$ is a sentence in the language of rings, then $k\models \chi$ if and only if $\mathbb{C}\models \chi$. Our specific statement $\chi$ is known to hold over $\mathbb{C}$, and therefore it holds for any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. This method will also, for instance, allow one to deduce arithmetic properties of abelian varieties over real closed or $p$-adically closed fields by appealing to the known properties of such varieties over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

EDIT: Thank you very much to Alex Kruckman for his wonderful answer! It was exactly what I was looking for. However, it still remains to see if this "interpretation" works in definable families like the above $\mathcal{E}\rightarrow S$. Certainly this can be done in the way I described. Suppose we have a family of abelian varieties $\mathcal{A}\rightarrow S$ (i.e. an abelian scheme) with $S=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_m))$. Now if $A_s/k$ is the fiber over a $k$-point $s:\operatorname{Spec}(k)\rightarrow S$, then we can interpret any sentence $\phi$ in the language of groups into an "equivalent" sentence $\psi$ in the language of rings (relative to $A_s$), in the sense that Alex indicates in his answer. But if we look carefully at this interpretation, we ought to find that the corresponding sentence in the language of rings only uses integers and the elements defining $A_s/k$, i.e. the elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in k$ corresponding to the morphism $s$. In particular, we should be able to think of $\psi$ as a sentence in the language of rings with parameters $\psi(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ coming from the definable set $S(k)$, and in fact if $s'=(b_1,\dots, b_n)\in S(k)$, then we should find that the interpretation of $\phi$ relative to $A_{s'}$ is exactly $\psi(b_1,\dots, b_n)$. The point here is that the addition, inverse, identity section, etc. that define $\mathcal{A}/S$ are *uniform* in their parameters. That's what it *means* to be an abelian scheme. From here we can conclude that the $k$ satisfies the first-order sentence "for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in S, \psi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$" if and only if each fiber $A_s(k)$ satisfies $\phi$.

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe it helps to note that an algebraic group, viewed internally in, say, the gros Zariski topos over $k$, is really a group, and what you are doing is expressing properties of that group internally in that topos and then “un-internalizing” them (meaning, translating the internal statement in the topos to a statement in the ambient set universe). If you are not familiar with topoi, [Ingo Blechschmidt's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.03685) should help explain.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your goal is to reduce (some) statements of algebraic geometry to first-order sentences about the field, so that you can invoke  Lefschetz's principle for first-order logic. But Lefschetz's principle holds for a broader class of statements, intended to capture much of what's needed for algebraic geometry. See: J. Barwise & P. Eklof, "Lefschetz's Principle," J. Algebra 13 (1969) 554-570.

Comment: @AndreasBlass's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455728/interpreting-group-theoretic-sentences-as-statements-about-algebraic-groups#comment1179945_455728), clickably: [Barwise and Eklof - Lefschetz's principle](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(69)90117-3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In model theory / mathematical logic, the "unpacking" procedure you're describing is called an [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)) (of the group $G$ in the field $k$).

In general, an intepretation of an $L$-structure $M$ in an $L'$-structure $N$ consists of:

- An $L'$-definable set $D\subseteq N^n$.
- An $L'$-definable equivalence relation $\sim$ on $D$.
- For each $k$-ary function symbol in $L$, an $L'$-definable function $(D/{\sim})^k\to (D/{\sim})$.
- For each $k$-ary relation symbol in $L$, an $L'$-definable subset of $(D/{\sim})^k$.

Such that the resulting $L$-structure with domain $D/{\sim}$ is isomorphic to $M$.

Now it's an easy theorem (proven by induction on the structure of formulas) that given an interpretation of $M$ in $N$, for any first-order $L$-formula $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_k)$, there is a first-order $L'$-formula $\psi(y_1,\dots,y_k)$ (where each $y_i$ is an $n$-tuple of variables) such that for all $a_1,\dots,a_k$ in $D$, $N\models \psi(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ if and only if $M\models \varphi(f([a_1]_\sim),\dots,f([a_k]_\sim))$, where $f\colon (D/{\sim})\to M$ is the isomorphism. In particular, for every $L$-sentence $\varphi$ (i.e., formula with no free variables), there is an $L'$-sentence $\psi$ such that $M\models \varphi$ if and only if $N\models \psi$.

In your example, $L = \{e,\cdot,^{-1}\}$ (the language of groups), $L' = \{0,1,+,-,\times\}$ (the language of rings), $M = G$, and $N = k$. Then $D\subseteq N^1$ is the set defined by $x^2 = 1$ (i.e., $D = \{-1,1\}$), $\sim$ is the discrete equivalence relation (defined by $=$), the constant $e$ is defined by $x = 1$, the multiplication $\cdot$ is defined by $\cdot$, and the inverse function $^{-1}$ is defined by $y = x^{-1}$ iff $xy = 1$.

[By the way, where are the terms $(a+bx)\cdot (a+by)$ coming from in your "unpacking"? Shouldn't the translation of commutativity of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to the ring language be $\forall x\,\forall y\, (x^2=1\land y^2 = 1\rightarrow xy = yx)$?]

For your second question: Yes, for any projective algebraic group $G$ defined over $k$, the group $G(k)$ is interpretable in $k$. The idea is the same as above, but we can take $D$ to be the subset of $k^{n+1}\setminus \{\overline{0}\}$ defined by a system of homogeneous polynomials, and then quotient by the equivalence relation defined by $(a_0,\dots,a_n)\sim (b_0,\dots,b_n)$ iff $\exists \lambda\, (\lambda\neq 0\land \bigwedge_{i=0}^n \lambda a_i = b_i)$.

More generally, for any abstract variety defined over $k$, the set $S(k)$ of $k$-points of $S$, equipped with whatever polynomially defined functions and relations, is interpretable in $k$. The idea is pick a finite affine cover, define the disjoint union of these affine pieces, and quotient by the equivalence relation defined by identifying points from these affine pieces on their overlaps.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex this is exactly what I was looking for! The $a+bx$ terms are what the elements of $R$ look like, but after reading your answer thoroughly, I agree that your interpretation is what I was intending to do.

Comment: I have a follow-up question, if you don't mind: does this notion of "interpretation" also capture the idea I outlined of a definable family of group varieties? For example if $S$ is a definable set parametrizing $L$-structures, can we translate first-order  sentences in $L$ into first-order sentences in $L'$ that depend on $S$?  Perhaps this is what would be meant by "interpreting with parameters"?

Comment: @NathanLowry "Interpretation with parameters" means that some elements of the interpreting structure $N$ are used as parameters in the definitions of all the data of the interpretation. Let's say we have an $m$-tuple of parameters $b\in N$ used in an interpretation of $M$ in $N$. If we replace the tuple of parameters $b$ with new variables $y$ in all the defining formulas, then substituting a different choice of parameters $b'$ for $y$ would give us a new interpretation with parameters $b'$. (continued)

Comment: Typically, some choices of $b'$ might not work, in the sense that the formulas could fail to define equivalence relations or definable functions, or we might get an interpreted structure of the wrong kind (e.g., not a group). So usually we'll want to fix a definable set $B\subseteq N^n$ such that for all $b'\in B$, substituting $b'$ for $y$ in our formulas gives a meaningful interpretation of a structure $M_{b'}$. I would call this a "definable family of interpretations". The theorem would then translate $L$-formulas to $L'$-formulas with $y$ as additional free variables.

Comment: So an $L$-sentence $\varphi$ about the interpreted structure would translate to an $L'$-formula $\psi(y)$ with free variables $y$, such that for all $b'\in B$, $N\models \psi(b')$ if and only if $M_{b'}\models \varphi$, where $M_{b'}$ is the interpreted structure using $b'$ as parameters. In other words, we can talk uniformly about the whole family of structure $(M_{b'})_{b'\in B}$.

Comment: After thinking about this for a bit last night, I came to the same conclusion that you outline here. I edited my post with some speculation as to how one might argue uniformly about the whole family, and you have confirmed my suspicions. Thanks a lot!